# Redis Length growing

Tags: redis, logstash, elastic-stack

Our Pipeline:
VMware-Netflow  ->  Logstash  -> Redis -> Logstash-indexer -> 3xElastic

Data I have gathered:

- I notiticed in kibana that the flows coming in were 1 hour old, then
  2, then 3 and so on.
- Running 'redis-cli llen netflow' shows a very large number that is slowly increasing.
- Running 'redis-cli INFO shows pretty constant input at 80kbps and output at 1kbps.  I would think these should be near equal.
- The cpu load on all nodes is pretty negligible.

What I've tried:

- I ensured that the logstash-indexer was sending to all 3 elastic nodes.
- I launched many additional logstash instances on the indexers, redis now shows 40 clients.

I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: Have you done load tests on individual components? E.g. how many logs can your indexer process per min. How many log lines do you get from the Logstash Shipper per min?

Comment: It's essentially down to input vs how quickly the Indexer can process the logs. In my experience Redis itself is extremely fast and it's usually something to do with Logstash which is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: rebooted all three elasticsearch nodes, and life is good again.

I inadvertently disabled elasticsearch as an output, and sent my netflows into the ether.  The queue size in redis dropped down to 0 in minutes.  Although sad, this did prove that it was elasticsearch not logstash or redis.

I watched the elastic instances, and it seemed like something was wrong with the communication between them.  All three showed logs indicating that 2/3 were dropping out of the cluster, and taking forever to respond to cluster pings.  What I think was happening, is writes were accepted by elastic, and just bounced around a while before being written successfully.

Upon rebooting them all, they negotiated correctly, and writes are happening as they should.